# git on cygwin - pushing has to be done 3 times in a row

Tags: git, cygwin

I have a cygwin and git that comes with it (1.7.9). I have a repository, which is on network shared drive (r:/). All of my colleagues uses git with windows (and repo has been created with windows MSYS git 1.8.3.msysgit.0). My OS is Win 7.

When I am performing git push, it sometimes ends with "fatal - bad object error". The strange thing is, that if I perform 3 consecutive git push, it performs correctly with the last one.

Does anybody has idea why it happens? And is it safe to do push 3 times?

```
rb@L18021: ~math/test/pc_env$ git push
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 702 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
fatal: bad object e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968
fatal: bad object e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968
error: unpack should have generated e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968, but I can't find it!
To /cygdrive/r/E51/Internal/850_DevTempRepo/LAS_PAS.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (bad pack)
error: failed to push some refs to '/cygdrive/r/E51/Internal/850_DevTempRepo/LAS_PAS.git'
rb@L18021: ~math/test/pc_env$ git push
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 702 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
fatal: bad object e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968
fatal: bad object e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968
error: unpack should have generated e4cecab43c0122ade56f6ff6e13d5c98e1462968, but I can't find it!
To /cygdrive/r/E51/Internal/850_DevTempRepo/LAS_PAS.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (bad pack)
error: failed to push some refs to '/cygdrive/r/E51/Internal/850_DevTempRepo/LAS_PAS.git'
rb@L18021: ~math/test/pc_env$ git push
Counting objects: 12, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 702 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
To /cygdrive/r/E51/Internal/850_DevTempRepo/LAS_PAS.git
   84e96ef..e4cecab  master -> master
rb@L18021: ~math/test/pc_env$ git --version
git version 1.7.9
```

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera I ***do not recommend using a Git GUI like TortoiseGit*** for most Git operations, because GUIs abstract away too much understanding of how Git actually works. If you want to learn how to use Git correctly, effectively, and proficiently, I always highly encourage people to learn to use Git from the command line instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use msysgit Bash like the rest of your coworkers? I like to use Cygwin too, but their packaged version of Git (1.7.9) is relatively very old, so I switched over to using msysgit Bash for most of my work now, though sometimes I'll still switch back to Cygwin for other tasks.

Comment: @Cupcake : Thanks sir,splendid argument, however doesn't tortise-git comes with command line tools as well

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera if it does, I've never found them nor used them. Regardless of whether TortoiseGit comes with command lines tools or not, I still encourage people to learn to use ***pure Git from the command line*** instead.

Comment: @Cupcake : I guess you are right,even though i've been using github for a while i still doesn't know how to access it from command line

Comment: @Cupcake I am preferring usage of cmd-line version of git with the same reason. I still want to use cygwin version because of integration with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating git. 
For that run cygwin’s setup binary again (and just go with the default for updating your whole cygwin environment).

I think I had the problem described but I only tried pushing twice. As suggested by Cupcake in the comments I suppose the cause of the problem was the old git version shipped with cygwin. I updated today from 1.7.9 to 2.0.4 and it worked.

I don’t have any clue whether it is safe or not to push 3 times in your situation.